# Complex unit vector raised to irrational power

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Say I have:

$z = \exp(i (4-2\pi))$

I'm not sure which is the correct way to compute $z^\pi$. Indeed:

$z^\pi = \exp(i (4-2\pi))^\pi = \exp(i (4-2\pi) \pi) = \exp(-i 2 \pi^2) \neq 1$

apparently however I could also simplify $\exp(i (4-2\pi))$ in $\exp(i 4)$ first and then get $\exp(i4)^\pi = \exp(i4\pi)=1$

I would opt for the first to be the correct one. Still there must be some constraint I'm missing about when $\exp(ix)^y = \exp(ixy)$ holds.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Multivalued_function).

Comment: $(a^b)^c$ is not necessarily equal to $a^{bc}$, or as you have disguised it here, $\text{exp}(b)^c$ is not necessarily equal to $\text{exp}(bc)$.  It will be true that they are equal when the base is positive real, and the exponents both real... but as soon as you allow the base to be negative or non-real or if you allow the exponents to be non-real it can fail.

Comment: Several related questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcomplex-analysis%5D+irrational+power+answers%3A1+is%3Aquestion

Comment: What is the questions?

Comment: The implicit question is: which way is the correct one to proceed? Although at this point I guess both are correct (and possibly incomplete).